# Pywinrm is connecting to remote host but not to the underlying SQL server .Says Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server, winrm, pywin

My requirement is to run an EXE which is at host "abc". The EXE also communicates with downstream SQL server. pywinrm version is 0.4.3.

```
import winrm
s = winrm.Session("abc", auth=("username","passowrd"), transport="ntlm")
    r = s.run_cmd('D:\Jobs\echoprint.exe')//This also need to connect to SQL Server
    print(r)
```

Unfortunately, I get this error saying its not able to connect to SQL server
SqlException in GetTableLayoutFromSP: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. Any help is appreciated?

Comment: Are you running this in Windows? If so are you logged in to an Active Drectory domain user?

Comment: I am running it from Debian/Linux. My machine is logged into Active Directory domain user.

Comment: Sounds like Python is not picking up the `kinit` token for whatever reason. `ANONYMOUS LOGON` basically just means the token was invalid.

Comment: Any recommended solution?

Comment: Is kinit stands for kerberosinit? 

I was simply using non-kerberos version? Do you think I need to use kerberos?

Comment: Well you haven't shown any of the application code, but I'm guessing your conenction string is using Trusted Connection, which implies Kerberos authentication. On Windows it's not a problem as you are already logged in, but on Linux you need to use `kinit` to authenticate to Kerberos first.